# Pagination is showing Big arrows/ Didn't work properly?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade, laravel-pagination

I used simple Laravel pagination command of {{$blogs->links()}} for blog post but showing errors. After research, I put as an argument on the "links" method, a version of Bootstrap which works right:

$posts->links('pagination::bootstrap-4')

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Let me quote from the DOC

> The **links** method will render the links to the rest of the pages in the
> result set. Each of these links will already contain the proper page
> query string variable. Remember, the HTML generated by the **links**
> **method is compatible with the Tailwind CSS framework**.

If you want to use **bootstrap** as your default paginator style

Add to your `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider`:

```php
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
 
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 */
public function boot(): void
{
    Paginator::useBootstrapFive();
    Paginator::useBootstrapFour();
}
```

Take a look at the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/pagination) for more details